# How to display data AutoCompleteMode Combobox encrypted local database - C#

Tags: c#, encryption, combobox

I was using the ComboBox with AutoCompleteMode=Suggest and DataSource=  in my application and it was working fine. But when I encrypted my local database with a password, it stopped working. The ComboBox is now empty. Any ideas How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you any exception?

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted"? You configured it to use authentication and set a username/password? Have you updated this information for this data connection inside Visual Studio?

Comment: No, I don't have any exception and I have just set an username/passwordd.